# How to Write UTF-8 in Mifae Card

Tags: c#, utf-8, rfid, mifare

I try to make Member Membership Management Program using MifareCard & NFC Reader.

In this code, English is normally, but other languages are broken.

Like this
Write Data to Card  "北京",    read wrote Data  "yyyy" 
Write Data to Card  "서울",    read wrote Data  "yyyy"
Write Data to Card  "さくら",  read wrote Data "yyyyyy"

How can I use UTF8 Encoding for Write Data in to MifareCard?

**Main.CS**

```
#region Write_Data
private void Button_Click_2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (connectCard())// establish connection to the card: you've declared this from previous post
    {
        byte[] bytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(textBox2.Text);
        String insert_Value = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
        submitText(insert_Value, Combo_W.Text); // 5 - is the block we are writing data on the card
        Close();
    }
}

//submit data method
public void submitText(String Text, String Block)
{

    String tmpStr = Text;
    int indx;
    if (authenticateBlock(Block))
    {
        ClearBuffers();
        SendBuff[0] = 0xFF;                             // CLA
        SendBuff[1] = 0xD6;                             // INS
        SendBuff[2] = 0x00;                             // P1
        SendBuff[3] = (byte)int.Parse(Block);           // P2 : Starting Block No.
        SendBuff[4] = (byte)int.Parse("16");            // P3 : Data length

        for (indx = 0; indx <= (tmpStr).Length - 1; indx++)
        {
            SendBuff[indx + 5] = (byte)tmpStr[indx];
        }
        SendLen = SendBuff[4] + 5;
        RecvLen = 0x02;

        retCode = SendAPDUandDisplay(2);

        if (retCode != Card.SCARD_S_SUCCESS)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("fail write");

        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("write success");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("FailAuthentication");
    }
}

// block authentication
private bool authenticateBlock(String block)
{
    ClearBuffers();
    SendBuff[0] = 0xFF;                         // CLA
    SendBuff[2] = 0x00;                         // P1: same for all source types 
    SendBuff[1] = 0x86;                         // INS: for stored key input
    SendBuff[3] = 0x00;                         // P2 : Memory location;  P2: for stored key input
    SendBuff[4] = 0x05;                         // P3: for stored key input
    SendBuff[5] = 0x01;                         // Byte 1: version number
    SendBuff[6] = 0x00;                         // Byte 2
    SendBuff[7] = (byte)int.Parse(block);       // Byte 3: sectore no. for stored key input
    SendBuff[8] = 0x60;                         // Byte 4 : Key A for stored key input
    SendBuff[9] = (byte)int.Parse("1");         // Byte 5 : Session key for non-volatile memory

    SendLen = 0x0A;
    RecvLen = 0x02;

    retCode = SendAPDUandDisplay(0);

    if (retCode != Card.SCARD_S_SUCCESS)
    {
        //MessageBox.Show("FAIL Authentication!");
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

// clear memory buffers
private void ClearBuffers()
{
    long indx;

    for (indx = 0; indx <= 262; indx++)
    {
        RecvBuff[indx] = 0;
        SendBuff[indx] = 0;
    }
}

// send application protocol data unit : communication unit between a smart card reader and a smart card
private int SendAPDUandDisplay(int reqType)
{
    int indx;
    string tmpStr = "";

    pioSendRequest.dwProtocol = Aprotocol;
    pioSendRequest.cbPciLength = 8;

    //Display Apdu In
    for (indx = 0; indx <= SendLen - 1; indx++)
    {
        tmpStr = tmpStr + " " + string.Format("{0:X2}", SendBuff[indx]);
    }

    retCode = Card.SCardTransmit(hCard, ref pioSendRequest, ref SendBuff[0],
                         SendLen, ref pioSendRequest, ref RecvBuff[0], ref RecvLen);

    if (retCode != Card.SCARD_S_SUCCESS)
    {
        return retCode;
    }

    else
    {
        try
        {
            tmpStr = "";
            switch (reqType)
            {
                case 0:
                    for (indx = (RecvLen - 2); indx <= (RecvLen - 1); indx++)
                    {
                        tmpStr = tmpStr + " " + string.Format("{0:X2}", RecvBuff[indx]);
                    }

                    if ((tmpStr).Trim() != "90 00")
                    {
                        //MessageBox.Show("Return bytes are not acceptable.");
                        return -202;
                    }

                    break;

                case 1:

                    for (indx = (RecvLen - 2); indx <= (RecvLen - 1); indx++)
                    {
                        tmpStr = tmpStr + string.Format("{0:X2}", RecvBuff[indx]);
                    }

                    if (tmpStr.Trim() != "90 00")
                    {
                        tmpStr = tmpStr + " " + string.Format("{0:X2}", RecvBuff[indx]);
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        tmpStr = "ATR : ";
                        for (indx = 0; indx <= (RecvLen - 3); indx++)
                        {
                            tmpStr = tmpStr + " " + string.Format("{0:X2}", RecvBuff[indx]);
                        }
                    }

                    break;

                case 2:

                    for (indx = 0; indx <= (RecvLen - 1); indx++)
                    {
                        tmpStr = tmpStr + " " + string.Format("{0:X2}", RecvBuff[indx]);
                    }

                    break;
            }
        }
        catch (IndexOutOfRangeException)
        {
            return -200;
        }
    }
    return retCode;
}

//disconnect card reader connection
public void Close()
{
    if (connActive)
    {
        retCode = Card.SCardDisconnect(hCard, Card.SCARD_UNPOWER_CARD);
    }
    //retCode = Card.SCardReleaseContext(hCard);
}
#endregion

#region Read_Data
private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string text = verifyCard(Combo_R.Text); // 5 - is the block we are reading
    byte[] bytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(text);
    textBox1.Text = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
}

public string verifyCard(String Block)
{
    string value = "";
    if (connectCard())
    {
        value = readBlock(Block);
    }

    value = value.Split(new char[] { '\0' }, 2, StringSplitOptions.None)[0].ToString();
    return value;
}

public string readBlock(String Block)
{
    string tmpStr = "";
    int indx;

    if (authenticateBlock(Block))
    {
        ClearBuffers();
        SendBuff[0] = 0xFF; // CLA 
        SendBuff[1] = 0xB0;// INS
        SendBuff[2] = 0x00;// P1
        SendBuff[3] = (byte)int.Parse(Block);// P2 : Block No.
        SendBuff[4] = (byte)int.Parse("16");// Le

        SendLen = 5;
        RecvLen = SendBuff[4] + 2;

        retCode = SendAPDUandDisplay(2);

        if (retCode == -200)
        {
            return "outofrangeexception";
        }

        if (retCode == -202)
        {
            return "BytesNotAcceptable";
        }

        if (retCode != Card.SCARD_S_SUCCESS)
        {
            return "FailRead";
        }

        // Display data in text format
        for (indx = 0; indx <= RecvLen - 1; indx++)
        {
            tmpStr = tmpStr + Convert.ToChar(RecvBuff[indx]);
        }

        return (tmpStr);
    }
    else
    {
        return "FailAuthentication";
    }
}
#endregion
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert a `string` from one encoding to another like this

```
byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(myString);
myString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
```

See the docs [here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/character-encoding)

Comment: I changed 
when Data write
byte[] tmpStr = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(Text);

                for (indx = 0; indx <= (tmpStr).Length - 1; indx++)
                {
                    SendBuff[indx + 5] = tmpStr[indx];
                }
When read
tmpStr = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(RecvBuff);
But It also break...

Comment: Using to 
byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(myString);
myString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
solved